# How to convert a single bit to char?

Tags: c++, string, file, binary

I want to convert a read bit from a binary file to a char so I can add it to a string that would represent a binary format of a file's content. My task is also to read a file byte by byte. I have a following code:

```
while(f.get(c)){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        cout << ((c>>i)&1);     //I would like to convert a single bit to a char here
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to do it since if I simply add `((c>>i)&1)` to string I get a binary form for every bit read so `0` becomes `00000000`. Can anyone help me? Thank you in beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single bit `b` (is, or) can be converted to a `bool`. In your case `bool b = (c>>i)&1;`

So you may want to code `b?'1':'0'` using the [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

You could also code `"01"[(unsigned)b]` (or just `"01"[b]`) or `(char)('0'+(unsigned)b)` but I feel it is less readable to humans (and both only work because `(unsigned)b` can only be 0 or 1).

Comment: Is the cast needed? `"01"[true]` means `*("01"+true)`. Overload resolution is unambiguous as only `true` needs to be promoted.

Answer (score 2):

You need [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/) from `#include <bitset>`

```
while( f.get(c) ) {
    bitset<sizeof(c) * CHAR_BIT> currentByte(c);
    cout << currentByte;
}
```